# Is it possible to condense this?

Tags: if-statement

I want to write something like:

```
if (x == a || x == b || x == c || x == d)
{
    //...do something
}
```

in a way that is shorter and not repeating code?

Edit: This is in java, sorry.
Also, a, b, c, and d are constants.

Comment: And the language would be...?

Comment: @Lurker - what about c ?

Comment: Are `a` through `d` variables? Or are they contiguous, enumerated constants? The example isn't really very clear. By the way, I don't really consider the given example as a bad case of "repeating code" necessarily.

Comment: Please specify the language type

Answer (score 0):

```
if (in_array(x, array('a', 'b', 'c'))) {

}
```

Checks whetever the value of x exists in the array.

You did not provide the programming code used, I used a PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine, easy to read and not complex. Clarity is king. The variable names are not that great but that might be because the snippet is out of context. In most languages the logic will be evaluated in a 'short-circuit' manner such that the first True result you get will terminate evaluation of the expression and continue on to your 'do something' code.

Answer (score 0):

If this is C# and the type of `x` is `int`, you could use Linq to rewrite the condition as follows.

```
if( new int[]{ a, b, c, }.Contains(x) )
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C#

```
List<int> list = new List<int> {a, b, c, d};
if (list.contains(x))
{
}
```

or

```
if (new List<int> {a, b, c, d}.Contains(x))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the language I think it would be best to try and capture the intent of the operation instead of explicitly checking the boolean result.

You might not gain anything in terms of making it shorter but at least the intent is clear

```
if (SomethingThatReturns1() || 
    SomethingThatReturns2() || 
    SomethingThatReturns3() || 
    SomethingThatReturns4())
                {
                    //...do something
                }
```